# Cannot redeclare show404()

Tags: php, function

**`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare show404() (previously declared in /Users/patrikbelis/www/todo/_inc/config.php:33) in /Users/patrikbelis/www/todo/_inc/config.php on line 36`**

Here's function that I also tried to rename for etc. mine404pagetoshow() but still not working

Also I searched in project for functions but have only 3... in config, delete, edit.php

**code in config.php**

```
    <?php

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(-1);

// require stuff
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';




// global variables
$base_url = 'http://localhost:8000/todo';


// connect to db
$database = new medoo([
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => 'todoapp',
    'server'        => 'localhost',
    'username'      => 'root',
    'password'      => 'root',
    'charset'       => 'utf8',

]);

// global functions


function show404()
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND");
    include_once "404.php";
    die();
}


 function get_item()
{


    // if we dont have id or its empty
    if ( ! isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id']) ) {
        return false;
    }

    global $database;

    $item = $database->get("items", "text", [
        "id" => $_GET['id']
    ]);

    if ( ! $item ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $item;

}

?>
```

and that's how I'm loading it to php file - **code in delete.php, edit.php**

```
<?php
    require_once '_inc/config.php';
    $item = get_item();
    if ( ! $item ) show404();
?>
```

**404.php**

```
<?php

include_once "partials/header.php"

?>

<div class="page-header">
    <h1><a href="/todo" style="color:black">404</a></h1>
</div>

<p>
    _not found
</p>

<?php include_once "partials/footer.php" ?>
```

Trying to fix it for a while and also I'm reading some questions here and on google but can't find solution

Comment: So far it looks like you have the same file twice ...

Comment: Is any of the code you posted for config.php? If not, then it could be something in there (and/or other files). And what is line 36? We need to know what code relates to what files. Plus, this seems to be db related.

Comment: Sorry, I missed one word: "looks like you have included the same file twice" (and the error message + your code for `show404()` suggests just that). If you cannot figure out how it's done (where it's included 2nd time) -- surround your function declaration with `function_exists()` guard

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes functions are in config.php

Comment: Search for `show404` in all your files, you'll find it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- only 3 :) in config.php , delete.php and edit.php so where i put it.

Comment: I suggest you edit your question with the code and their related filenames. That will expedite things for everyone ;-)

Comment: `in /Users/patrikbelis/www/todo/_inc/config.php on line 36` - Your config.php file as posted only contains 29 lines. Are you sure there isn't a function of the same name in there that you didn't show us? You have been given an answer below also. See what that does. and if 404.php contains the same function, then that could be the problem.

Comment: posted full config.php file @Fred-ii-

Comment: show us full edit.php, delete.php

Comment: Is it possible that `partials/header.php` (included from `404.php`) is including `config.php` again?

Comment: @patrikbelis please don't give use partial code, by hiding parts of something we cannot find the issue.

Comment: @UnixOne Yes header.php requiring config.php

Comment: seems like no require_once just require or include ?

Comment: @patrikbells then that's how you're re-including `config.php` assuming it's just a plain `require` and thereby re-defining the function.

Comment: @patrikbelis so You've found Your problem :)

Comment: yeah. I did the stupid mistake :) anyway thanks guys for helping me to find out the problem :)

Comment: everything is ok, but why You were hiding most parts of code? is it top secret code? (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare show404() (**previously declared in** /Users/patrikbelis/www/todo/_inc/config.php:`33`) in /Users/patrikbelis/www/todo/_inc/config.php `on line 36`

Seems like in `404.php` file You've another `show404()` function

```
   33 function show404()
   34 {
   35     header("HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND");
   36     include_once "404.php";
   37     die();
   38 }
```

I know it's not solution, but workaround:

```
  if(!function_exists('show404')) {
      function show404()
      {
          header("HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND");
          include_once "404.php";
          exit(0);
      }
  }
```

Please check also files that You use in one script run, You'll find:

```
require '_inc/config.php';  // or include
```

that cause problem

Comment: The `if(!function_exists...` here is a copout. The root cause should be identified and resolved, whether it's including the same file multiple times, or defining function in another file.

Comment: yes, I know, the author of question was hiding most part of code, that's why I've just wrote this code :)